# FullCalendar 2.1.x compatibility with touch devices

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone, touch, fullcalendar

I would like to know how to make it compatible Full Calendar Version 2.1.x with touch devices (iPad, Windows phone, android).

I found several solutions (jQuery UI Touch Punch 0.2.3) for older versions using jquery UI hack for iPad,  it does not work.

Adam support for touch devices for a future version would be amazing !

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

We had the same problem, eventually I gave up on [touch punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/) and attempted a different plugin I found here: https://github.com/joshgerdes/jquery.ui.touch.

Along with:

`eventAfterRender: function(event, element) {
     element.addTouch();
}`

This seemed to fix the problem of drag and drop on the latest version of fullcalendar ("~2.x").

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly it doesn't, there doesn't seem to be any impetus to get it working with touch devices and apparently that's not worth documenting so you don't find out until you try it or finally discover where the issues are posted surprisingly *not* on github where the project is hosted.

I realize it's an old project but touch device support should be the first consideration these days so not even documenting that it only works with desktop browsers properly is pretty crappy.

As of right now I can find no way to use 2.1.x with touch devices at all so I think you might want to look elsewhere as will I.

Comment: Given the lack of response, I think I hit a nerve I have done since tests that have proven insufficient. 
Do you know of a solution that does the same thing with the support of touch?

Comment: We decided it works as basically a read only display with the one thing that *does* work on mobile being to open an item so we created a UI for editing an opened item as an alternative to the built in dragging options.  I'm mystified as well that there are so few options for mobile scheduling components.  If we had time we'd fork full calendar and mobilize it as there is clearly a need for it.

Comment: I use the same technique, this time. I would have preferred to use the same functionality on desktop, too bad. thank